# Is there a "Shift" version of Scroll Lock?

Tags: capslock, shift, scroll-lock

Caps Lock is to Shift as Scroll lock is to...

If that wasn't clear, I want to press down on a key + an arrow key, and then depress everything afterwards and it should go back to how it was.

Edit: Asking mainly for it's Excel functionality.

Comment: There isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this by using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/download/).

Once you have installed it, it creates a file called `AutoHotkey.ahk` in your Documents folder. Replace the default content with the following:

```
!Up::
oldState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "On" : "Off" 
newState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
SetScrollLockState %newState%
Send {Up}
SetScrollLockState %oldState%
return

!Down::
oldState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "On" : "Off" 
newState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
SetScrollLockState %newState%
Send {Down}
SetScrollLockState %oldState%
return

!Left::
oldState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "On" : "Off" 
newState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
SetScrollLockState %newState%
Send {Left}
SetScrollLockState %oldState%
return

!Right::
oldState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "On" : "Off" 
newState := GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
SetScrollLockState %newState%
Send {Right}
SetScrollLockState %oldState%
return
```

Afterwards you need to run the `AutoHotkey.exe` program and it will put an icon in the system tray to show that it is running.

Now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> to temporarily override scroll-lock when pressing the arrow keys.